# Get Activecontrol inside multipage

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get the name of the`Listbox` that I just selected ("ListBox1"). 
Caveat: `ListBox1` is located within `Multipage1` (on the first tab).

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
Dim m As String

m = Me.ActiveControl.Name
MsgBox (m)
End Sub
```

Since I have selected the `ListBox1`, I'm expecting the message box value to be *ListBox1*. 
 Instead I am receiving *Multipage1*.

What should I be doing differently?

Comment: I tested your issue and was able to recreate it. But if I transfer the controls outside of the multi-page, the code correctly outputs the control name. Not sure if this is a bug or what but that is the only thing I can suggest, if it is vital to get above code working, abandon `Multipage`?

Comment: I have to use the `Multipage` because of the large number of listboxes inside the form - it's a scheduling program.

Answer (score 1):

It helps to consider MultiPage, Pages, and Frames as subforms.  If a subform control is active then the parent form will return the subform as the ActiveControl.

Here is the proper way to drill down to the actual ActiveControl.

```
Function ActiveControlName(Object As Object) As String
    Dim Obj As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Obj = Object.ActiveControl
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        ActiveControlName = ActiveControlName(Object.ActiveControl)
    Else
        Set Obj = Object.SelectedItem
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            ActiveControlName = ActiveControlName(Object.SelectedItem)
        Else
            ActiveControlName = Object.Name
        End If
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

### Demo

[image]

Comment: Your code gives me the name of the active page. What I am trying to get is the name of the `ListBox` that is set inside a frame, on that page. I've tried tweaking your code, but I'm not getting it to work - can you help me get to the `ListBox`?

Comment: I think the difference is that I have a frame around the `ListBox` and you do not.

Comment: I modified the code to recursively drill down the actual ActiveControl.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Comment: Great post! Learned something today! :)

Comment: @l42 Thanks glad you liked it.

Answer (score 0):

An old post but I landed here with the sames issue.  Unfortunately this answer didn't work for my scenario (controls positioned within nested frames on a multipage).  But user6432984 gave a great headstart.

The key to the proper solution is that the active control (reported by "ActiveControl") is the top level control that is active on the userform.  It may have either:

1) Another nested "ActiveControl",
2) A "SelectedItem"
3) Neither of the above - in which case it really is the "ActiveControl" you want.

So, the technique to drill-down requires that you determine which of 1), 2) or 3) above you have.  If you don't have 3) keep throwing whichever of 1) or 2) you do have into the recursive function until you find 3):

```
Function ActiveControlName(Object As Object) As String
'modified my Malcolm Farrelle
Dim Obj As Object
Set Obj = Nothing
On Error Resume Next
Set Obj = Object.ActiveControl
On Error GoTo 0
If Obj Is Nothing Then
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Obj = Object.SelectedItem
    On Error GoTo 0
End If
If Obj Is Nothing Then
    ActiveControlName = Object.Name
Else
    ActiveControlName = ActiveControlName(Obj)
End If
End Function
```